# Pandas: Simple string manipulation to create a YEAR, MONTH, and DAY columns from DATE object (xx/xx/xx)

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, data-cleaning

The DATE column of a data frame has variables like 7/18/2019 cast as objects. I want to use string manipulation to make Year, Month, and Day columns from the DATE column. Thank you. I cannot recast (school assignment parameters, and our prof says we can use stack overflow.)

I tried df.DATE.str.contains('1/') to find all that began with 1 (January) but A) this only returned Booleans and B) '1/' could occur at multiple points in the string and doesn't necessarily select for this first number (i.e. 6/1/1/19).

My failed attempt thus far results in

```
dfmerge[['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY']]= dfmerge.DATE.str.split(pat='/')
```

I did it! I added expand=true after pat

Comment: Good for you! Please [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) the technical solution that you discovered.

Answer (score 0):

```
dfmerge[['MONTH', 'DAY', 'YEAR']]= dfmerge.DATE.str.split(pat='/', expand=True).
```

ANSWER